# Get value from hyperlink to open page 2

Tags: php

I use this code for hyperlink:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    // set up a row for each record
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='http://www.mysite.com/get_info.php&NR_PROCESSO=" . >$row->NR_PROCESSO . "'</a>Editar</td>";                            
    echo "<td>" . $row->NR_PROCESSO . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->ESTADO . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->DATA_PEDIDO . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->AVALIADOR . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->NOME_CLIENTE . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

On hyperlink press, it goes to:
http://www.mysite.com/get_info.php&NR_PROCESSO=981237923

How do i get this value and where do i put the code?

Thanks.

Best regards

Comment: "how do i get this value and where o put the code?"

Comment: I mean where in page 2 (get_info.php), after hyperlink press, do i have to put some code and what code to get the variable NR_PROCESSO ?

Comment: do you refer to $_GET['NR_PROCESSO']?

Comment: if i have to put $_GET['NR_PROCESSO'], where do i have to put it to get value in page 2? i tried $_GET['NR_PROCESSO'] in page 2, but it seams it continues to not open the page...

Comment: paste your code in order to help you

Comment: it's too long to put it in here..~

Comment: <?php

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM..."))
{
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
echo "<tr><th>column names</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='http://www.mysite.com/get_info.php&NR_PROCESSO=" . $row->NR_PROCESSO . "'</a>Editar</td>";                            
echo "<td>" . $row->NR_PROCESSO . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->ESTADO . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->DATA_PEDIDO . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->AVALIADOR . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->NOME_CLIENTE . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else...
$mysqli->close();
?>

Comment: this is from first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mysite.com/get_info.php&NR_PROCESSO=981237923
There is a typo in your link: after .php there should be question mark (?) and then you can add all the variables as follows: NR_PROCESSO=981237923&NR_SOMETHINGELSE=123
If you want to access the variable use $_GET['NR_PROCESSO'] in the second page..

Comment: but the 981237923 is the variable...
echo "<td><a href='http://www.mysite.com/get_info.php&NR_PROCESSO=" . $row->NR_PROCESSO . "'</a>Editar</td>";

Answer (score 1):

You could put that code anywhere you want.
Just do

```
if(isset($_GET['NR_PROCESSO'])){
    //your code here
}
```

And shouldn't it say

```
echo "<td><a href='http://www.mysite.com/get_info.php?NR_PROCESSO=" . $row->NR_PROCESSO . "'>Editar</a></td>"; 
                                                     ^
```